# How detect if MIT Kerberos is installed on OS?

Tags: shell, kerberos

I'm working in a script called "[Kerberize It!](https://github.com/brunowego/kerberizeit/blob/develop/kerberizeit.sh)" with objective to install MIT Kerberos. Before continue I'm looking for a way to detect if the machine have Kerberos installed.

This script is similar to [`wait-for-it`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), commonly used by docker images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `dpkg -s` for aptitude, `rpm -q` form yum/zypper and `apk -e info` for apk. With this pre-check I can verify if package have already installed.